# Is this possible to use 'stream' module in 'node' and 'hls.js'? #2216

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, http-live-streaming, hls.js

Is this possible to use 'stream' module in 'node' and 'hls.js'? (Electron app - working with main and renderer process)
What i want to do is, I want to download mp3 files and encrypt them and then decrypt them and then play them!
But i don't want to create new file after decrypting them, I'd like to know is there any way to do something with hlsjs?

```
const fs = require('fs');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./a.mp3');
// I don't want to create b.mp3
// I want to parse it directly and pass it to hls.js
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./b.mp3');

readStream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  // Can i pass this chunk to hls.js?
  console.log('chunk', chunk);
  writeStream.write(chunk);
});
```

If it's not possible, 
Can i create temporary files in memory with nodejs?

Comment: cross-posted on github: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/2216

Comment: Because i need the answer